# I think I have an idea of how to stop global warming, where can I share it?

Tags: colonization, geostationary, life, technology, terraforming

It is quite simple space technology that will require a lot of funds and some physical and biological research, but I think it is realistic to create it because the idea is simple (build special space station).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about space exploration.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out [XPRIZE CARBON REMOVAL](https://www.xprize.org/prizes/elonmusk#:%7E:text=XPRIZE%20Carbon%20Removal%20is%20aimed,in%20history%2C%20an%20extraordinary%20milestone.).

Comment: Thank you I will do it.

Comment: also good luck, we need it!

Comment: It is already exist known solution similar to my idea - space sunshade :) I should just google before even post but thank you.